# Image not displaying in php from mysql

Tags: php, html, sql

i am trying to display database value in php, my php code is below

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "teia";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from registers ORDER BY ID DESC limit 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name     = $row['firstname'];
        $lastname = " $row[lastname] ";
        $mobile   = " $row[mobilenumber] ";
        $exp      = " $row[experience] ";
        $photo    = " $row[Photo] ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

this is what i tried to get image

```
<?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Photo'] ).'"/>';?>
```

every data is being displayed except the image, may i know what is the reason for it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk0Mo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pdD.png)

Comment: Is the `Photo` (is it suppose to be a capital P?) a blob field in the database? What does this row output `$photo    = " $row[Photo] ";`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  its varchar

Comment: What does the field contain? A url? A base64 encoded image?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the field is just showing the image title

Comment: Then why would you expect the image to be shown when you base64 encode the title? Where is the actual file? You either need to store the complete image as a binary in the database (as a blob) and use base64 on it like you've done, or store the url to the image and just echo that in the `src` "as is".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its outputting blank unloaded image

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how should i fix it.. what should i do to my table

Comment: First of all, you should be using prepared statements. Second, why are you wrapping all the variables except `$name` in quotes? Third, what does your table look like?

Comment: @krimaeus - The variable definitions are valid. I'm guessing that the OP is wrapping the other echoes just to get the space between the values. There's also no need to prepare the query if it's just a hard coded query.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson which data type excatly should i use

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah, but why would you want to do that?
sighkin: That depends on what you are storing inside the table.

Comment: Didn't I just write that in my third comment?

Comment: @krimaeus - Let's stick to the subject at hand (the actual issue) instead of questioning the formatting. That's just personal preference.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am not that good in sql, i am seeing some data types like "blob,tinyblob,longblob,binary" which is better?

Comment: The easiest way would be to store the url to the image in the database (as a varchar) and then just echo it: `<img src="<?= $row['Photo'] ?>" />`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i tried <img src="<? echo $row['Photo'] ?>" /> but its not doing anything

Comment: Is the file uploaded? Does that variable now contain the URL? If it still just contains the title, it won't work. The title is of no use what so ever at this point. You need the _URL_ to the image (or the image name and add the path when echoing, like: `src="/upload/path/<?= $row['Photo'] ?>"`).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i stored it as blob in database and now the field is showing [BLOB - 15 Bytes]

Comment: How did you store it in your database? You should rewrite the question to include how you store the images and your table schema (column names and types).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson have now added the database image in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general practice is to store images in directories on the file system and store references to the images in the database. e.g. path to the image,the image name, etc.. Or alternatively, you may even store images on a content delivery network (CDN) or numerous hosts across some great expanse of physical territory, and store references to access those resources in the database.

As you mentioned that, you have store just title of the image. As well as, you have to store the image to particular path.

```
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

You can store the name of the image like:

```
$image=basename( $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"],".jpg");
```

When you want to render then just do like this:

```
<img src='uploads/$image_name' height='150px' width='300px'></td>"
```

Where $image_name will be retrieve from the database

Comment: i want to store it in database only

Comment: @sighkin - Why? Images are files and lives best in the file system. In most cases, storing images in a database is a bad idea. If you just want to show an image, you would need to query the database, get the image and output it using PHP. If you get a list of users from the database (including the image column), PHP would need to keep all user data (including all image data) in memory. If you just store the URL, PHP won't need to load the images at all, just the paths/filenames.

Comment: my image is stored like this  if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
      $image = $request->file('Photo');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

     Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Photo=$filename;
    }

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you tell me how to echo the image from my code

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $base64_image?>" height="50px" weight="100px">

Comment: @ShivaniPatel its showing 
Undefined variable: base64_image

Comment: obviously, it shows. I mean to say that your blob image data retrieve from the database are placed over here. I suppose, that you retrieve the blob data of image from the database and store into base64_image  variable.

Comment: i didnt understand what you said, can u tell a solution

Comment: Can you please try the code which i have added recently.

Answer (score 0):

For Inserting image into database as blob format:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
//you keep your column name setting for insertion. I keep image type Blob.
$query = "INSERT INTO products (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  
$qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Try to retrieve the image like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: You should really use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping the data that's being used in the queries